# Javascript Tooltipster HTML content not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tooltipster

I've been working with older versions of Tooltipster to HTML content (mostly divs with another picture and some text) on mouseovers over text or pictures, using the now deprecated writing HTML in the title method. After the update I want to switch to the current standard and I'm not quite managing it.

Jquery and Tooltipster are loaded correctly in my header, (verified that by triggering some Tooltipster error messages), and all tooltip instances in the page I'm working on have their class name changed to 'tooltipstered', so I'm pretty sure the script recognizes those too.

The page is written in php (using codeigniter) and the content produced by a foreach loop, the $key variable is numerical here.

```
echo "<img src='{$value['bild']}' style='width:60px; height:60px;'>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<span class='tooltip' data-tooltip-content='#$key'>";
echo "{$value['name']}";
echo "</span>";
echo "<br>";
```

This outputs:

```
<span data-tooltip-content="#1" class="tooltip tooltipstered">Schütze</span>
```

(There are 24 such instances on the page all in all, the tooltip-content attribute ranging from #1 to #24 so)

My tooltips are generated in a similar fashion, by another foreach loop:

```
<div class='tooltip_templates'>
<?php 
foreach ($klassenbaum as $key => $value){

echo "<span id='$key'>";
echo "<h1>Text für Klasse Nummer $key!</h1>";
echo "</span>";
}

?>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="tooltip_templates">
<span id="1"><h1>Text für Klasse Nummer 1!</h1></span
</div>
```

I've been following the instructions provived here:
http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started under section 5. I'm quite clueless where my error is, the tooltips aren't showing up at all on a mouseover. And even more curiously: Some script is executed on hovering, because the spans containing the tooltip disappear from the code afterwards. (At least by checking the firebug console).

Thanks beforehand for any help on this!

Comment: Hi, can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Working on it! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi, you forgot a `>` after `span`. Besides, in HTML4 you can't use a numeric as an id, maybe that's why: try `x1`, `x2`, etc. or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Made a very poor mistake - the code seems to be indeed correct; the error was the CSS file from Tooltipster not loading correctly due to a spelling mistake.